# 本文でリンクしないで、リンク集に表示できますか？

Tags: サポート

[金額の、正規表現の書き方:数字の前の0（ゼロ）を削除する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/69972/%E9%87%91%E9%A1%8D%E3%81%AE-%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%AE%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E6%96%B9%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AE0-%E3%82%BC%E3%83%AD-%E3%82%92%E5%89%8A%E9%99%A4%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

上記の私の投稿で、「金額の、正規表現の書き方」のリンクが二重表示されている気がします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

リンク集がページのサイドバー部分に表示されるものを示しているのであれば、本文に URL を書くので正しいです。そのまま本文に書いてください。

[image]

リンク集にはその質問からリンクした質問だけでなく、その質問へリンクしている質問も表示されます。たとえば今回リンクなさっている [金額の、正規表現の書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/23609) の「リンク集」に [金額の、正規表現の書き方:数字の前の0（ゼロ）を削除する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/69972/) が表示されていることからもこの挙動が分かります。

このため、質問の文脈として必要なリンクはそのまま本文に書いてください。リンク集はあくまで質問のネットワークを分かりやすくするためのものであって、本文を読む際に必ず参照されるようなものではありません。